# String literals concatination. What does this syntax mean in JS?

Tags: javascript

I've just found a decent bug in my JS code, which I'm porting from C++:

```
var x = "aaa"
        "bbb";

//In C++: x="aaabbb" 
//In JS: x="aaa"
```

Surprisingly there were no error (in node.js).

How does JS handle "bbb"?

Comment: arguably you're seeing a silent error, but in JS, it's not a formal error to have orphan expressions.

Comment: In c++ (and c) a new line is considered a concatination (as in your case the silent char \\), in javascript it is considered a new line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Semi-colons are not required in javascript to end a statement. Those statements were interpreted as set `x` to `"aaa"` and execute next statement `"bbb"` which is just an arbitrary string.

You can think of it as the semi-colon being auto inserted so the statements become

```
var x = "aaa";"bbb";
```

Comment: OK, thanks! Have to keep this in mind. Actually the string was an ´SQL DELETE´ expression , where "bbb" was the ´WHERE´ part :-(

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is inserting a semicolon after the first line.

So, what you're really doing is

```
var  x = "aaa";
         "bbb";
```

It evaluates the first line, which assigns "aaa" to x and then evaluates the second line which  doesn't assign "bbb" to anything.

You might want to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) about the rules for semicolon insertion in JS

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't handle it. What happens is that JavaScript will insert a semicolon for you, and `"bbb"` is merely an expression:

```
var x = "aaa"; // JS inserts this semicolon
"bbb"; // this is a valid expression but does nothing
```

This feature is known as [ASI](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9). If you put a `+` it will concatenate the strings:

```
var x = "aaa" +
        "bbb";
```